# HTML5 Web SQL Transactions skipped without error when touch triggered in IOS

Tags: javascript, iphone, sql, ios, html

I'm experiencing problems making database transactions on IOS devices.
If the user doesn't touch the phone, everything works like expected.
If the user taps/scrolls/touches the screen, some transactions directly call their successCallback, without ever calling the actual transaction callback.

Simplified example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Tk9rv/

To test, just open http://jsfiddle.net/Tk9rv/embedded/result/ in your mobile safari on IOS and do not touch the device while loading. You will see a list of debug messages being generated looking like this:

```
database is running
table will be cleared
store method called for '10'.
about to insert '10'.
transaction successful for '10'
store method called for '9'.
about to insert '9'.
transaction successful for '9'
store method called for '8'.
about to insert '8'.
transaction successful for '8'
[...]
```

Now, reload the page and while loading, scroll and tap randomly.
You will see some "about to insert..." messages are missing.

```
database is running
table will be cleared
store method called for '10'.
about to insert '10'.
transaction successful for '10'
store method called for '9'.
about to insert '9'.
transaction successful for '9'
store method called for '8'.
transaction successful for '8' <-- WHERE IS MY "about to insert '8'." ???
store method called for '7'.
about to insert '7'.
transaction successful for '7'
[...]
```

This is because the transactionCallback is completely skipped! But WHY? And WHY does the successCallback fire instead of the errorCallback?

[This is a simplified example, please do not tell me not to do this setTimeout stuff. In the real world, there is data being loaded async and then being inserted... :) ]

I think there is a similar problem here [HTML5 Web SQL transaction Missing In Action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8059548/html5-web-sql-transaction-missing-in-action/8727754#8727754) but there is no solution or hint either.

Any ideas? I'm stuck... Thanks!

Comment: Addon: Works in iOS 4.3, Fails in iOS 5

Comment: i have the same problem, let's hope iOS 5.1 helps

Comment: I'm still looking for a solution :( 
Waiting for iOS 5.1 is not an option since the page has to work with iOS >= 4...

Comment: increasing the timeout between transactions reduces the problem although not completely

Comment: yes, I've noticed that - but you can't rely on it :( but now that w3 cancelled their work on this html database solution, I do not think this will ever be fixed

Comment: Is it fixed now with the latest version of iOS?

Answer (score 9):

Our testing showed that this behaviour would also occur whenever the keyboard was displaying and would prevent transactions in an onblur or onfocus event (although, not onkey{down|up|press}).  Using setTimeout would cause terrible performance issues.  We had found that the .transaction() success callback would be triggered, even if the transaction callback was not called, so came up with this method that works well for us:

```
var oldOpenDatabase = window.openDatabase;
window.openDatabase = function() {
    var db = oldOpenDatabase.apply(window, arguments);

    var oldTrans = db.transaction;
    db.transaction = function(callback, err, suc) {
        var db = this;
        var params = arguments;
        var hasRun = false;
        oldTrans.call(db, function(tx){
            hasRun = true; callback(tx);
        }, err||function(){}, function(tx) {
            if(hasRun){
                if (suc != undefined)
                    suc(tx); 
                return;
            }
            else {
                oldTrans.apply(db, params);
            }
        });
    }

    return db;
}
```

This code checks that the transaction callback has fired in the success handler and, if not, gives it another chance.

Comment: The error handling for when you pass an invalid err or suc callback isn't always exactly the same as the native API, but for us it was a small price to pay to overcome this crippling failure in iOS WebSQL.

Comment: very cool solution, we've now implemented and are amazed that more people haven't found this iOS bug a major problem or maybe they didn't notice their data going missing.  good work @EionRobb.

Comment: Impressive! I want to use your solution, just one question: it re-launches the transaction only once or recursively until it succeeds? I mean, what if the 2nd attempt fails just like the 1st one?

Comment: @schory no, if it fails after the 2nd attempt, your error function callback will get notified

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a magical fix-all, at least not for me. I'm using this patch with the [asyncStorage](https://github.com/WebReflection/db) library and testing on iOS 7. I've duplicated the above code for the readTransaction function as well, but that hasn't fixed it. The modified code I am using can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/phMnhbUW). NONE of the handlers - callback, err, or suc, get called at any point, and NOTHING gets logged to the console.

Comment: It's not an issue on my end - the code works fine the first time I run it and I log every time right before the transaction function is called. iOS drops the transaction the second time through. I'll try to isolate a test case.

Comment: @TreyKeown our testing has shown that you shouldn't need this workaround code as of iOS6.0

Answer (score 0):

Web Workers and OpenDatabaseSync fix the same problem on my site.  Except web workers are not supported on iOS4.x and Android so we can implement the old way for those and web workers on iOS5.

The very basic example below uses a loop to do a single insert 500 times writing to the screen after each insert.  At the end a query is made to return the number of rows in the table.  Now we can see transactions are *not* skipped even with a lot of scrolling.

This example is designed so you can test the resilience to scrolling during the inserts on iPhone or iPad.

Two pages are required, an html page and separate javascript file for the worker.  So for the html page;

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" name="viewport"/>
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
    <title></title>
    <script src="../scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    {
    background-color:Black;
    }
    .number
    {
    color:#00FF00;
    font-family:Courier New;
    font-size:12pt;
    }
    button
    {
    position:fixed;
    right:5px;
    top:5px;
    padding:15px;
    }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var worker;
    $(document).ready(function () {

        worker = new Worker('worker1.js');
        worker.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
        $("#test").html(new Date().toLocaleTimeString() + " " + e.data.message + "<BR/>" + $("#test").html());
        if (e.data.complete == true) {
            worker.terminate();
        }
        }, false);
    });

    function stop() {
        worker.terminate();
    }
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" onsubmit="return false">
    <div id="test" class="number">
    <button onclick="stop()">Stop</button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and worker1.js ;

```
var wdb = {};
wdb.db = openDatabaseSync('test', '1.0', 'DB test', 1024);

doQuery("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(abc INTEGER PRIMARY KEY);");
doQuery("DELETE FROM test"); // optional

for (var i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
    doQuery("INSERT INTO test(abc) VALUES( " + i + " );");
    postMessage({ message: "Inserted " + i.toString(), complete: false });
}

var summary= doQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total FROM test;");
postMessage({ message: "Found " + summary.item(0).Total.toString() + " rows", complete: true });

function doQuery(sql) {
    wdb.db.transaction(function (tx) {
    rs = tx.executeSql(sql, []);
    });
    return rs.rows;
}
```

Comment: we also worked around this iOS bug using WebWorkers. But we now suspect that at least for focus/blur event interruptions (as opposed to touch/scroll event interruptions) it didn't solve the problem completely - only significantly "reduced" it...