# sqlite query in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, sqlite, ios5

We have the following query to fetch some programs from a channel guide based on whether they lie between certain date and time:

```
SELECT TITLE,duration, start_time FROM guide where (start_time  between '2012-02-17 09:00:00.0' and '2012-02-17 11:30:00.0' or datetime(start_time, duration || 'minutes') between '2012-02-17 09:00:00.0' and '2012-02-17 11:30:00.0' or (start_time < '2012-02-17 09:00:00.0' and datetime(start_time, duration || 'minutes') > '2012-02-17 11:30:00.0')) order by start_time
```

The query works properly until iOS 4.x. But in iOS 5, it skips certain results. The strange thing is if I add a leading space to `'minutes'` as `' minutes'`, it starts working fine even in iOS 5.

If anyone has any idea why this happens, please advise.

Comment: I had a very similar problem and found out how to get around the skipped results problem by using HTML5 Web Workers and OpenDatabaseSync.  Maybe it will help your problem, there is an example on SO question number [8741000](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741000)